# Where should "feedback always welcome" link in the common footer point in MSO?

Tags: feature-request, easter-eggs

The footer links are the same for all the sites.

Good.

The **feeback always welcome** one is pointing on meta.stackoverflow.com on all the sites, as intended.

But, whould it be nice to send it elsewhere on MSO since were're already here, such as the post that makes MSO the official feed-back way ?

I just think of it as as some kind of *easter-egg*.

Comment: Maybe some web site with a dash?

Comment: meta.meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*perhaps* "[ask question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)"? Another option is to simply drop it, but a lot of people (in the link's target audience) visiting "meta" may be doing so because their question on SO/SF/SU has been migrated; so IMO it is reasonable to *have* a link.

Comment: +1 for *ask question*. Dropping it just feels wrong.

Comment: I think this change should happen on all sites. meta should link to meta home and feedback should link to meta/ask.

Answer (score 1):

It should redirect to (meta)+.stackoverflow.com; down to 3 or 4 levels (or, whatever), each appending a new Meta where applicable.

Obviously, the actual content should be plain old Meta.  It'd be a funny easter egg, and I can't imagine it'd be too difficult to implement.

I think Joel's mentioned being a fan of:
[image: Being John Malkovich]
anyway...